# Custom 404 page css?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I've been making a simple site using thymeleaf for my html pages, and typically my css is linked a little something like this.

```
<link href="../static/css/bootstrap.css"
    th:href="@{css/bootstrap.css}" rel="stylesheet" media="screen"/>
```

and I was under the impression that the `th:href` tags used the normal href to find the correct path for the CSS.

My custom 404 is in a different directory so its css link is a little different, and when I test it in browser it works, but when the server is actually started it doesn't.

```
<link href="../../static/css/bootstrap.css"
      th:href="@{css/bootstrap.css}" rel="stylesheet" media="screen"/>
```

What am I missing that keeps it from working when the server is started?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you're using:

```
<link href="../static/css/bootstrap.css"
    th:href="@{css/bootstrap.css}" rel="stylesheet" media="screen"/>
```

The `th:href` tag will eventually have some final value which will replace the original `href` value.

For example:

Let's say that `th:href="@{css/bootstrap.css}"` will end up to be

```
href=/css/bootstrap.css
```

that value of: `/css/bootstrap.css` will replace the `../static/css/bootstrap.css` value of the original href.

with that being said, the page source code to figure out what value does your href is getting from the `th:href` tag

Comment: Thanks for the info! This eventually lead to me to realize what the problem was. Apparently the 404 page wasn't being parsed as a thymeleaf page, which makes sense I suppose, and all I had to do was treat it like normal html.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest taking a look in your spring context file and check whether resources are mapped to a folder.

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="<path to resources>" />
```

Comment: The resources aren't mapped that way... So that wouldn't seem to be the issue.